# CssSquidSensor and JavaScriptSquidSensor both fail with parse errors when Byte Order Marks are present

Tags: javascript, c#, css, .net, sonarqube

We are attempting to analyze our .Net projects with SonarQube.  These projects  contain both CSS and JavaScript in addition to C#.  I think we have our projects configured correctly, both the CssSquidSensor and the JavaScriptSquidSensor execute for each project but they fail to parse our css and js files due to the presence of byte order marks at the beginning of the files.  Is this just a bug that needs to be corrected or is there a way to configure these sensors to account for BOMs?

This is with SQ 5.1, C# plugin 4.0, Css plugin 1.1 and JS plugin 2.5.

Below is some example output from our logs.

```
10:27:55.947 INFO  - Sensor CssSquidSensor
10:27:56.072 ERROR - Unable to parse file: E:\jenkins\workspace\sq-test\Web.Subscribers\Account\Integrations\OAuth\ToUStyles\global.css
10:27:56.072 ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 2:

 1: @import url('navigation.css');
     ^

10:27:58.895 INFO  - Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor
10:27:59.285 INFO  - 188 source files to be analyzed
10:27:59.301 ERROR - Unable to parse file: E:\jenkins\workspace\sq-test\Web.Subscribers\Dashboards\RenderChart.js
10:27:59.301 ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 2:

 1: function RenderChart(HdnOptionsID, HdnDataID, containerID, filterID) {
     ^
```

**UPDATE:**

Having put the recommended `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` setting in place, JS files look good but some CSS files, notably those starting with `at-rules` are still failing as follows:

```
02:33:13.743 ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 2:

 1: ?@import url('navigation.css');
     ^
```

Comment: This definitely seems to be a bug or an encoding issue as this famous byte order mark is supposed to be handled. Do you know which encoding is used ? To help us reproduce the issue, could you just provide a JavaScript source file (for instance by creating a simple GitHub project)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  You can see pull down some example files here: https://github.com/kbaltrinic/Stackoverflow-question-30482045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8` in your `sonar-project.properties` file for UTF-8 BOM characters to be properly taken into account.

Now, I was able to reproduce the parse error on CSS files with the CSS plugin 1.2, which does not yet understand UTF-8 BOM characters.

However, on C# and Javascript files, I did not face any issue with the C# plugin 4.0 nor the Javascript plugin 2.6.

Issue created on the CSS plugin: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-css/issues/88

Comment: Adding the sourceEncoding property (I added it to the sonar-runner.properties file), solved the issue for the JS files, however, at least some of css files are still failing to parse.  Not 100% certain of this, but the apparent pattern is that css files that have an `at-rule` (i.e. start with an @ sign) as the first non-BOM character, are the ones that are still failing to parse.  The error is slightly different from the above listed one though in that the carrot is pointing to the @ sign now rather than the first character past the @ sign.

Comment: I have updated the original question to include an example of the new error output for CSS files.

Comment: Yes this is expected - the developers of the CSS plugin have pushed a fix into the master to support UTF-8 BOM characters, which will be part of the next plugin release (1.3).